# Simple system to receive millions of records and produce a single file without duplicates

Tags: mongodb, concurrency, architecture, database

I have a system where 10s of client machines are sending objects to a single server. The job of the server is to aggregate all the objects (removing duplicates - and there are many) and produce a file every hour of the objects received the previous hour.

I tried MongoDB for this task and it did a good a job but there is the overhead of going over all the records by the end of each hour to produce the file. I am now thinking about gradually building the file as data is received stopping by the end of the hour and starting a new file and so on.

I don't need to do any searching or querying of the data, just dropping duplicates based on a key and producing a file of all the data. Also the first time I receive a record, the duplicates come within a maximum of 3 minutes afterwards.

Which system should I use? Do you recommend a different approach?

Comment: Why not just have a unique index. Inserting a "duplicate" will fail

Comment: That is what I am doing now with MongoDB but I want to avoid the full db scan every hour.

Comment: The only other problem is that the alternative is to introduce race conditions. The other way to do query magic but that will introduce a full scan as well, either way you need a full scan of a index to stop this from introducing race conditions

Comment: I wouldn't use ttl indexes to do this but instead drop the collection every time you need to empty it due to numerous reasons including space allocation and fragmentation

Comment: Just wondering if this is wandering away from the point of the answer I provided. The point there was to **add** an "additional" key for the hour of insertion to the unique keys. In this way, entries outside the hour maintain their own "de-dup" within their own hour. Also you have a key to fetch the documents from rather than scan a whole collection.

Comment: I have chosen to go ahead with MongoDB with indexing to take care of dups and dropping the collection every time a batch is consumed. Thanks Sammaye and Neil Lunn for helping out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend, even though you state in your comments you don't like the idea of it, to use indexes. You can use a unique index on these fields and you use that as a method to insert.

This does, as you rightly point out, produce a full scan however whichever race condition free route you take (the only way to ensure non-duplicates really) you will need to do a full index scan, either by query or by index insertion.

Index insertion probably the best router here, at the end of the day the performance makes it not really matter.

As for dealing with removing your old records I would not use a TTL index. Instead it would be much better to just drop your collection when your ready to receive a new batch, not only will this be a lot faster but it will also send the collection to `$freelist`s instead of adding the documents from the TTL index to a deleted bucket list potentially causing fragmentation and slowing down your system.

Comment: That looks like a good approach if I have to use MongoDB but I really don't have to. I feel there maybe a more lightweight solution to my problem. If I use MongoDB and just dump the the collection for the past hour as json file, will I avoid the full db scan for that collection?

Comment: @MajidAlfifi you will still have to dedup the file somehow, whether it is a full JSON file scan each insert or full MongoDB BSON file each scan, MongoDB would definitely be the quicker way

Answer (score 0):

Consider this document:

```js
{ 
   "name" : "a",
   "type" : "b",
   "hourtag": 10,
   "created": ISODate("2014-03-13T06:26:01.238Z")
}
```

Let's say we set up a unique index on this for `name` and `type`, another `hourtag` property, which the value you of you add to the document representing the hour of day it was inserted. Also add a `created` date if there is not something already and we set another index on that

```js
db.collection.ensureIndex({ hourtag: 1, name: 1, type: 1})

db.collection.ensureIndex({ created: 1, { expireAfterSeconds: 7200 })
```

The second index is defined as a [**TTL**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/) index, and set the `expireAfterSeconds` value to be 2 hours.

So you insert your documents as you go, adding the property for the "current hour" that you are in, and the duplicate items will fail to insert.

At the end of the hour, get all the documents for the "last" hour value and process them.

Using the "TTL" index, the documents you no longer need get cleaned up after their expiry time.

That's the most simple implementation I can think of. Tweak the expiry time to your own needs.

Defining the `hourtag` **first** in the index order gives you a simple search, while maintaining your "duplicate" rules.